# How do I implement jPanelMenu?

Tags: theme-development, jquery, navigation

I have serious problems trying to implement [jPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com/) to the theme I'm building. The theme is nearly finished, I'm just trying to figure out this menu and I can finally start using it. Anyways, if anyone can help me understand how I can implement this to my site I'd be grateful :)

I think my main problem is that I still haven't grasped how to properly implement jQuery scripts and link them up to a generated element, like the nav-bar in Wordpress.

This is what I've done this far:

1. Downloaded jPanelMenu and put it in a js folder.
2. Used this code to implement it in functions:

   ```
   function jpanelmenu_scripts_with_the_lot()  {  
       // Register the script like this for a theme:  
       wp_register_script( 'jpanelmenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jpanelmenu.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), '20120208', true );
       // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:  
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jpanelmenu' );  
   }  
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jpanelmenu_scripts_with_the_lot' );`
   ```
3. Then i call the navigation in header.php:

   ```
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_class' => 'menu' ) );
   ```

This is where I'm stuck with what I'm supposed to do. I'm doing something wrong, because at this moment i get no results..

Michael

Comment: What do you have so far? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: @DavidKryzaniak I've updated my questions with what I've done as of now.

Comment: You need to actually call the jpanaelmenu using some javascript, which is documented on the site you linked

Comment: @Wyck Alright, where should I implement it? In the head section, or right after/before I call the navigation?

Comment: You would call it on dom ready, but at that point you should be referring to the jpanelmenu documentation. Remember, jPanelMenu is not a WordPress plugin, it's a generic javascript library for the frontend. It doesn't know anything about your calls to `wp_nav_menu`, you need to tell it what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can "initialize" the script any time after it has been loaded on the page. I usually do that in `wp_footer` (Especially if you enqueue the script in the footer) but you can add it to `wp_head` too.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpa_107420_footer_script' );

function wpa_107420_footer_script(){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
            var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
            menu: '#custom-menu-selector',
            trigger: '.custom-menu-trigger-selector'
        });
    });
</script>

}
```

You'll need to modify the script part per the instructions on the jPanelMenu plugin. That part's off-topic here, but this is how you'd add the script to WordPress.